# Use network cable connection over wireless

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi

I have a laptop which is always connected to the wireless network in our office. 
At my desk i also have a network cable which, of course, gives me a much better network speed. The problem is that when i plug in the cable, my laptop stays connected to the wireless network.

Can i fix this with some setting?

What i want is that when i plugin the cable my laptop should switch to using the LAN.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because your computer is still connected to the wireless, doesn't mean it's using it. Your computer is quite capable of being connected to multiple networks. It will choose what it perceives to be the best connection.

If you're convinced this isn't working correctly, please goto the command prompt and paste the output for the following two commands:

```
ipconfig /all

route print
```

We'll be able to determine which connection is being used by default then, and confirm whether or not your laptop is assigning the correct metric.

Comment: Isn't it quite possible/likely that both networks will be using the same default gateway meaning this won't shed much light on the situtation?

Comment: @RobinGill route print will list the interface IP address as well as the gateway, so we can cross reference that with ipconfig to figure out which interface has what metric. (Unless there's an easier way?)

Comment: Thanks Dan. We've done like you said and compared the info we got from both commands. Made some changes to the metric setting and now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done using windows built in functionality. Assuming you are using win7, go to control panel, network and internet, network connections, then press the alt button, click advanced, advanced settings, than change the order of the network adapters to suit your preference.

For some daft reason, from what I've seen, wireless connections are normally listed above wired connections.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misunderstanding, this has no bearing on the interface metric. Indeed, on my machine, the WLAN is at the top but has a higher metric than the LAN connection. You can manually change the metric by going to the advanced TCP/IP settings in each adapter, but I think this should be left alone unless there is a specific reason to change it. Lower number = higher priority

Comment: I was going off the descriptions in those dialogue boxes but sounds like you are correct Dan

Answer (score 1):

there are 3rd party tools that can do this such as [wirless auto switch](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/)

when you plug in into your lan it should have a higher priorty and metric compared your wirless so all traffic should be routed thru there. also you can a lways disable manually from the network and sharing control panel:)